# "PRINT" command in Assembly

Tags: assembly, cpu

first of all i want to point out that i am not a native speaker, so please, dont mind my mistakes :) So, as it goes, i do have big problems with a simple assembly command, the thing is, this command is a "powerful" way to interact with the user. Here it comes:

Im building a CPU in Logisim (Nothing that Special, i am trying to get comfortable with that program, and i am trying to improve my "skills"). And with that, i am programming an assembly translator in Java (Assembly input, binary and hexadecimal output fitting to the instruction set of the CPU). But i am encountering a big problem...^^

i actually planned on adding a --PRINT "text"-- command, the assemblytranslator would generate a 7 Bit ASCII number for every letter and produce the output like this:

Assembly input:
PRINT "hello world"

Output for the CPU

PRINT h

PRINT e

PRINT l

PRINT l

PRINT o

PRINT (space)

[...]

This is because my CPU can only print one char at once :( 
Well, the problem with this occurs when trying to perfom a BRANCH-command.

The line in my Translator Program says, for example, Line: 2, and in this line you'll print a 5-char-long text. The next command therefore will be in the 3rd line, but, however, the CPU just printed out 5 chars, meaning that the Programcounter now points to line 8, and the 3rd line in the Translator actually lies on the 8th line on the Programcounter.

How could i fix that? Adding a Special Register that increments after each "PRINT" command the CPU actually performs, and add it to the line you want to branch? Or does someone have a way better method to print chars to a screen?

Thanks for all answers in advance,

selle

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand this correctly. Your assembler has a print string macro that expands to several "print immidiate" instructions (presumably of 2 byte size). And you have an instruction to (conditionally) skip the next instruction. Lets say this instruction is called ez (Execute on Zero). So code like this:

```
  ez print "Hello"
```

will assemble to something like:

```
1234h ez
1235h print 'H'
1237h print 'e'
1239h print 'l'
123bh print 'l'
123dh print 'o'
123fh ...
```

And you want the ez intruction to automatically skip five intsructions instead of just one. Right? One way to implement it could be to have one bit in the print instruction to indicate that is't linked so the ez instruction can continue to skip instructions until one lacks this bit. But IMHO this seems a bit too complex for the CPU design. I think it's reasonable to excpect programmers to know that print string generates several instructions and require them to write:

```
  enz bra skip_print
  print "Hello"
skip_print:
```